# Silverlight clientaccesspolicy.xml

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint-2013

We have Silverlight Application with RIA web service. URL: https://mysite.mydomain.com/services/mysitewebservice.svc

Also, we have a Sharepoint (SharePoint 2013) site hosted in separate domain. URL: https://mysharepointsite.mydomain.com

The Silverlight RIA service is called in SharePoint Silverlight Web Part.
I placed the **"clientaccesspolicy.xml"** file in the Silverlight root site (URL: https://mysite.mydomain.com/clientaccesspolicy.xml) and I can view this file in IE v11 browser. Compatibility view is ON.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="*"/>
  </allow-from>
  <grant-to>
    <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
  </grant-to>
</policy>
```

But calling the service in SharePoint Site SL Web Part. an exception error still occurs.

```
"Load operation failed for query 'GetMyData'. An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI 'https://mysite.mydomain.com/services/mysitewebservice.svc/binary/GetMyData?category=sales'. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by using internal types in the web service proxy without using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception for more details."
```

I read bunch of forums and articles but they all points to placing the clientaccesspolicy.xml in root site.

What is missing. Please help.